# How to add content onto a 'slice' from photoshop import

Tags: html

Sorry I'm completely new to this.
Ive designed a website in photoshop, and exported it 'for use with web and devices', (HTML/IMAGES). And I now want to be able to write and add content over a specific 'content slice' (images/GSGOPSD_13.gif (900px X 756px))

Here is the code i have from photoshop:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<center>
<body bgcolor="#2c2c2c" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (GSGOPSD.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1051" height="1235" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_01.gif" width="1050" height="359" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="359" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_02.gif" width="92" height="2" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
          <img src="images/GSGOPSD_03.gif" alt="" name="Twittr" width="55" height="62" id="Twittr"></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_04.gif" width="903" height="119" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_05.gif" width="13" height="873" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <img src="images/GSGOPSD_06.gif" alt="" name="Fbook" width="61" height="59" id="Fbook"></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_07.gif" width="18" height="117" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_08.gif" width="61" height="58" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_09.gif" width="55" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="57" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="images/GSGOPSD_10.gif" alt="" name="thumdown" width="60" height="59" id="thumdown"></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_11.gif" width="16" height="756" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <img src="images/GSGOPSD_12.gif" alt="" name="thumup" width="61" height="59" id="thumup"></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_13.gif" width="900" height="756" alt=""></td>
        <td> //------------I WANT TO ADD CONTENT OVER THIS IMAGE.
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_14.gif" width="60" height="697" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/GSGOPSD_15.gif" width="61" height="697" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="697" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="13" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="60" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="15" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="55" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="900" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

I thought that there would be a tut for this somewhere, and it would be a pretty simple thing, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try going through [this tutorial](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-convert-a-photoshop-mockup-to-xhtml-css) as I think it is what you are trying to aim for. You can relate it to your .psd along the way

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the image and then you will be able of insert content in the place where the image was. 
BUT I would not recommend use tables for designing your layout and also do not use fixed sizes for widht/height. This should be achieved with CSS

Comment: I did try doing that, but i could only enter text in the centre of the image then, it wouldn't let me enter it where i wanted (at the top). Okay ill look into doing it via CSS. Thanks.